# Postgres - add or subtract rows, depending on column value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `shipments`:

```
--------------------------
id | event    | quantity |
--------------------------
1  | received | 20       |
2  | sent     | 30       | 
3  | received | 45       |
```

I want a query that will sum all the `received` quantities, and subtract that value from the `sent` quantities. The query should return a result of `35`.

```
SELECT SUM(quantity)
FROM shipments
WHERE event = 'received';
```

This query returns `65`. How can I get it to also *subtract* the `sent` quantity (and get a result of `35`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression that puts a sign depending on `event`.

```
SELECT sum(CASE event
             WHEN 'received' THEN
               quantity
             WHEN 'sent' THEN
               -quantity
             ELSE
               0
           END)
       FROM shipments;
```